# Generating an FMU from a ROS node

Tags: ros, fmi

fmi_adapter looks like an awesome way to use an FMU as a ROS node. However, I don't see anything about the opposite/inverse problem - generating an FMU from a ROS node. Is there a reason that this is not possible in general? Or is it just an unusual pattern that no one has ever written a library for because it would be seldom used?

Answer (score 2):

I'm the developer of the fmi_adapter package but, admitted, never thought about the opposite direction. The big difference is that with an FMU you have an explicit specification of the variables (i.e., inputs and outputs), whereas with ROS these would have to be analyzed from the code (or can even be determined at runtime only). This would make a corresponding generator significantly more complex.